# How to deploy an owned token contract through Remix?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, metamask

I have deployed a regular ERC20-compliant token contract through the Remix compiler and MetaMask. After doing so, the deployed token shows up on Etherscan as a token.  However, when I try to deploy a token contract that is owned, it requires me to deploy the token contract and the owner contract separately, resulting in two isolated contracts that are from the same source code.

I use the very simple contract code from the official Ethereum website: 
https://ethereum.org/token#full-coin-code

Any help you be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to deploy the inherited contract (owned) separately, you just need to inherit it in your token contract by adding in `"is owned"` (example below).

Some more information about inheritance here.
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#inheritance

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract owned {
    function owned() { owner = msg.sender; }
    address owner;
}


// Use "is" to derive from another contract. Derived
// contracts can access all non-private members including
// internal functions and state variables. These cannot be
// accessed externally via `this`, though.
contract MyToken is owned {
    function kill() {
        if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner);
    }
}
```

Then in Remix, you can choose to *deploy MyToken only*.  Since the contract source code refers to owned (`"is owned"`), the `owned` code will be included in the compiled MyToken code.

**Deploy MyToken only:**
[image: Deploy MyToken only]